# Truncating all values in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to truncate column values in pandas after dividing by a number. Here are the two methods I have tried:

`df['new'] = int('%.0f'%(df['old']/12))`

`df['new'] = int(df['old']/12)`

Each time I get type errors:

```
cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

How can I solve this problem while avoiding these errors?

Comment: Does `df['new'] = df['old'] // 12` do what you're after?

Comment: @JonClements Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to convert the `Series` generated by the division into `int`.

```
df['new'] = (df['old'] / 12).astype(int)
```